# Entering minimum/ maximum number of rows in a SQL database

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, oracle10g, rdbms

How can we compel the user to enter a certain number of rows.
Like for example if a student has to take up 5 subjects for a course, how do we apply these types of constraints or how to force a user to enter minimum number of rows or maximum number of rows.

For Eg: **One student can select minimum 5 and maximum 6 numbers of subjects for that course.**
If we were to take a schema or database table keeping these constraints in mind how should we proceed to **CREATE** a table in oracle.

Comment: This sounds like something that should be in application/business logic, at the point the user selects something - presumably from a list in a GUI - rather than in database constraints. You could maybe have a materialized view on top of the table that counts rows and constrain that; but it would have to be deferred or you wouldn't be able to insert anything (unless you used `insert all`, perhaps). That seems a bit messy though.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no convienient way to enforce multi-row constraints. The problem is that your database will be violating the constraint at some point or another, even though you know it won't at the end. Like, after your student enrolls in one subject and is about to enroll in four more, you're in violation.

The key here is a **[deferrable constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#i1002273)**. These are not enforced until the transaction is committed. And even if a constraint is created as deferrable, by default, it will still be enforced immediately. So you will probably want to create the constraint as `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`. That would look something like:

```
subject_count     NUMBER(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
CONSTRAINT ck_subject_count CHECK ( subject_count BETWEEN 5 AND 6 )
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

OK, so you know you need a deferrable constraint. What do you put it on? You basically have two choices. You'll need a table that has one row per student and the total number of subjects for that student. You can either maintain that total as part of your application code, by a trigger that increments the column for each insert and decrements it for each delete, or by using an on-commit-refreshable materialized view. Personally, I'd probably use the table + trigger.